# Simple extension and the number of intermediate fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I saw from [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-finite-extension-that-contains-infinitely-many-subfields/) that if $K/k$ is a finite field extension, then the following are equivalent:

(1) The extension contains a primitive element (simple extension).

(2) The number of intermediate fields between $k$ and $K$ is finite

The author of the article didn't give the source or proof of this proposition and I wonder if this is true (either direction).

Comment: I have seen this before as the "primitive element theorem".

Answer (score 1):

This is true. Here's a sketch of the proof. Assume $k$ is infinite otherwise it's trivially true.

Suppose $K=k(\alpha)$ . Given an intermediate field $L$, look at $min.poly_L(\alpha)$. This is an injection from the set of intermediate fields to the set of factors of $min.poly_k(\alpha)$ in $\bar k[X]$ .The latter is a finite set and hence number of intermediate fields is finite.

Now assume the number of intermediate fields is finite. By induction it suffices to prove the claim for $K=k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$. Consider $k(\alpha_1 + t \alpha_2) \ , t\in k$.
All these fields can't  be distinct and hence $\exists s\neq t \in k$ such that $k(\alpha_1 + s \alpha_2) = k(\alpha_1 + t \alpha_2) $. It is easy to see that both $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ belong to this simple extension of $k$